# Помогите, не могу разобрать слова молитвы

Tags: славянизмы

Помогите пожалуйста понять молитву, спасибо:

*Господи Иисусе Христе Боже наш, вселивыйся в сердца двунадесятых апостолов нелицемерно, благодатию Всесвятаго Духа, сошедшаго в виде огненных язык, и сих устне отверзый, и начаша глаголати иными языки: Сам Господи Иисусе Христе Боже наш, ниспосли Того Духа Твоего Святаго на отроча сие (имя): и насади во ушеса сердца его Священныя Писания, яже рука Твоя пречистая на скрижалех начерта законоположнику Моисею, ныне и присно и во веки веков. Аминь.*

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что Вам непонятно.

Comment: "вселивыйся", "двунадесятых", "виде огненных язык", "устне отверзый, и начаша глаголати", "насади во ушеса сердца его", "яже рука Твоя пречистая на скрижалех начерта"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл такой:

*Господи Иисусе Христе Боже наш, вселившийся в сердца всех двенадцати апостолов в равной степени, благодатию Всесвятого Духа, сошедшаго в виде огненных языков (в день Троицы или Пятидесятницы) на апостолов и "отверзшего" их уста, так что они начали говорить иными языками: (Ты) Сам, Господи Иисусе Христе Боже наш, ниспосли Того Духа Твоего Святого на этого отрока или отроковицу (имя) и вложи в сердце его Священное Писание, которое Твоя пречистая рука начертала на скрижалях законодателю Моисею, на все времена: нынешнее, будущее и в вечности. Да будет так.*

Comment: Артем, можете помочь еще с одной молитвой, ну очень надо...спасибо

Comment: О преподобне и богоносне отче наш Сергее!
 Воззри на нас милостивно, и к земле приверженных, возведи к высоте небесной. Укрепи наше малодушие и утверди нас в вере, да несомненно уповаем получити вся благая от благосердия Владыки Бога молитвами твоими.
 Испроси предстательством твоим дар разумети науки и вся ны спосшествующими (с помощью твоих молитв) молитвами сподоби в день Страшного Суда шуия части избавитися, десные же страны общники быти и блаженный оный глас Владыки Христа услышати: «Приидите, благословеннии Отца Моего, наследуйте уготованное вам Царствие от сложения мира».

Comment: Хорошо, Эмма, помогу, только вечером теперь смогу.

Comment: Скажите, Эмма, что Вы не понимаете? Часть шуия и десная страна относятся к аду и раю соответственно (шуйца —левая рука, десница— правая). Что ещё непонятно?